# Angular : how to express condition in ng-if directive?

Tags: angularjs

How to express a condition in ng-if directive ?

Right now I tried this

```
<div ng-if="{ selectedTab == 'decoupage'}">
...
Syntax Error: Token '==' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 15 of the expression [{ selectedTab == 'decoupage'}] starting at [== 'decoupage'}].
```

I'm using Angular 1.2.0.

Comment: Watch out for this issue while using `ng-if` and Angular 1.2.0 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4852

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`ng-if` is already in an angular context so you can just do this:

```
ng-if="selectedTab == 'decoupage'"
```

For future reference:

- double curly braces: `{{ }}` -> are for interpolation
- single curly braces: `{ }` I've only seen in `ng-class` for boolean expression resolution.

Comment: Hoho - fastest answer ever ! that's working, thanks. You're actually so fast I can't even accept the answer yet ^^.

Comment: Glad to help.  I've made an edit about curly brace usage as well.  Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I've only seen single curly braces in ng-class expression as well now that I recall.

Comment: I was trying to pull a value with double curly braces into an ng-if, this helped me get it right, thanks!